# I need to know if php-ga allows me to send multiple Events at once

Tags: php, google-analytics

This is the code I am using

I want to send multiple Events at once without being obliged to add each time a trackerEvent() function

```
<?php
    require_once('autoloader.php');
    use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

    // Initializing ga tracker
    $tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('UA-XXXXXX-X', 'website.com');

    $event = new GoogleAnalytics\Event();
    $session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();
    $visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();

    $event->setCategory('cat');

    $event->setAction('act');

    $event->setValue(7);

    $tracker->trackEvent($event, $session, $visitor);

    print_r($tracker);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of [php-ga](https://github.com/thomasbachem/php-ga). You need to call `trackEvent` for each event you want to track as Google Analytics expects 1 request per event.

May I ask why that is a problem for you?

Comment: Instead of calling function every time. Can't we pass object or array for 1 particular category? Example: Test is category I have 1 action 1 Value & 2 action & 2 Value. So i need to call it 2 times

Answer (score 0):

When I am running this code to track an event, it is changing my Real Time Users for each request and giving a new user for the homepage. Is this normal?

```
use UnitedPrototype\GoogleAnalytics;

// Initilize GA Tracker
$tracker = new GoogleAnalytics\Tracker('', 'domain.com');

// Assemble Visitor information
// (could also get unserialized from database)
$visitor = new GoogleAnalytics\Visitor();
$visitor->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$visitor->setUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
//$visitor->setScreenResolution('1024x768');

// Assemble Session information
// (could also get unserialized from PHP session)
$session = new GoogleAnalytics\Session();


$event = new GoogleAnalytics\Event();
$event->setCategory('ads');

$event->setAction('loaded');

$event->setValue('1');

$tracker->trackEvent($event, $session, $visitor);
```

It seems as if the

```
$visitor->setIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$visitor->setUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Is not setting the correct visitor information as well. They all register as my server.

Answer (score 0):

You are restricted due to Google itself. Check this:

[Limit on Google Analytics asynchronous event push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474600/limit-on-google-analytics-asynchronous-event-push)

You can send 10 events at a time. After that, you are restricted to one per second.

You could do 10 times this:

```
$tracker->trackEvent($event, $session, $visitor);
```

... and that should work, but after that, somehow, you should have into account the time between request.