# Limit on Google Analytics asynchronous event push per account?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know there's a Google Analytics restriction for using the event tracking of them. I know there's a 10 events limit. Please refer here:

[Limit on Google Analytics asynchronous event push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474600/limit-on-google-analytics-asynchronous-event-push)

I did this test via Firebug to make sure:

```
var i = 0;

for(i=0; i<20; i++) { 
    _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Checkout", "Payment Failures", "reasoncode: " + i, 1, true]);
}
```

Like they say, it's 10 records at a time.

Now, I have a problem and consists that I'm losing data tracked on a website. Many users try to save events via _gaq.push and not all of it it's being stored. Is there a restriction also per Google Analytics account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/limits-quotas, each web property has a limit of 500 (non-ecommerce) hits per session.

Comment: Hey @nyuen, I made some tests with the new Google Measurement API with PHP and that api seems not to have the previous restriction. Anyway, thanks for your answer.